# Is there a way to name a flag for a bit field in Ghidra?

Tags: c, ghidra

In a line like this:

```
if ((my_variable & 0x80000000) == 0) {
```

Is there a way to label `0x80000000` as e.g. `FLAG_HAS_PROPERTY_GREEN`, or would I have to rely on comments for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

select SCALAR in decompiler window
right click ->Set Equate ("E" short cut)
type or select if available

a sample EQUATE as below

```
uVar6 = *(ushort *)param_2 & THIS_IS_MY_BAD;
```